# Go- authentication logic pattern in web app

Tags: go

I want to determine a simple and useful pattern for user authentication in a web app being written in golang.

I have come up with two patterns. First one is enabling the programmer to have his functions separate form the authentication logic, and has cleaner `HandleFunc` parts in `main()` that one can see only by loking `main()` to see what parts are under authentication control.

Second one is making programmer include a decision in every function deal with authentication required urls. An `if` statement checks by a `authp()` function defined else where.

Which one is better pattern for such necessity?

What are the better patterns for this job?

Is it even possible to pass a function to http.HandleFunc that has signature other than `func urlFunc (ResponseWriter, *Request)` bu like `func urlFunc (successFunc, failFunc)` or `func urlFunc (ResponseWriter, *Request, successFunc, failFunc)` as in `authenticationGateKeeper` function of **First Way** below, if not a suitable workaround for that?

```
//First Way
package main

func authGateKeeper(successFunc, failFunc) {
    if (authp()) {
        successFunc
    } else {
        failFunc
    }
}

func authp() boolean {
    //authentication logic, db query, or session check etc.
}

//usage in main
http.HandleFunc("/", authGateKeeper)



//Second Way; other alternative, in each function check pattern
func f(w, r) {
    if (authp()) {
    //function's processes
    } else {
    //the fail case function or processes
    }
}

func authp() boolean {
    //authentication logic, db query, or session check etc.
}

//usage in main
http.HandleFunc("/", f)
```

Comment: How can authp work without any arguments? Do you pass the request to it? And no, you cannot give HandleFunc a different signature, but you can of course wrap the gatekeeper in a function with the correct signature by making gatekeeper return a closure.

Comment: `authp` has arguments. I just for the sake of simplicity did not write it. possibly it will take the `ResponseWriter`, `*Request` parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to spin this, and it's arguable whether one is outright "better". I'd strongly suggest writing some middleware that wraps your routes and enforces the check, calling the wrapped handler only on success.

Note that I'm going to make a few assumptions here as you haven't told us how you're managing sessions (cookies? server-side?) and/or what kind of authorization you might need on top of authentication.

```
// Middleware - a function that sits in the 'middle' of your request processing.
func RequireAuth(h http.Handler) http.Handler) {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Assuming gorilla/sessions
        session, err := store.Get("name", r)
        if err != nil {
            // Raise HTTP 500
            return
        }

        // We'll assume you're storing the userID in the cookie|server session
        // upon login elsewhere.
        id := session.Values["userID"]
        // Probably returns a *yourapp.User
        user, err := db.GetUser(id)
        if err != nil {
            // Raise HTTP 500
            return
        }

        if user == nil {
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusUnauthorized), http.StatusUnauthorized)
            // Don't forget these 'naked' returns - if you miss one, your 
            // handler will keep processing beyond the error and result in
            // unintended side effects
            return
        }

        // Further checks here - i.e. checking user.Active == true, etc.

        // The userID matches one in the DB, so let's proceed
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }

    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

// And in your router - assuming just vanilla net/http
http.Handle("/", RequireAuth(yourHandlerFunc))
http.Handle("/", RequireAuth(someOtherHandler))
// Note that using gorilla/mux or goji can help give you "subrouters" so you
// don't have to wrap every single route with your middleware (messy, error prone)
```

I'd also suggest some reading on Go middleware[1](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware) composition[2](https://justinas.org/writing-http-middleware-in-go/) which will help you in the future.

If you want to call a custom error page, just write a handler - e.g. `UnauthorizedHandler` that satisfies http.Handler and just call `UnauthorizedHandler.ServeHTTP(w, r)` instead of `http.Error` along the way.

Comment: PS: I also wrote an article a while back on how to avoid the 'problem' of those naked returns and to centralise your HTTP status responses with custom handler types. You might find it useful: http://elithrar.github.io/article/custom-handlers-avoiding-globals/

Comment: Thanks. not sure yet on the sessions. Possibly I will use some new technology like JWT. But I am not quite sure of it.

Comment: Note that JWT's need something to catch and store them: (arguably) useful for API clients and Single Page Apps (e.g. an Angular app) but else cookies will be better for browser clients.

Comment: I will need and try to maintain a single code base for say authentication jobs of a Web service with same or almost same client and server side code. If for browser clients jwt is not a drawback or disadvantage, it will be better development ease I use jwt everywhere. Has it drawbacks with browser clients?

Comment: You need a JS front end to capture the token and store it in LocalStorage, so that's the major drawback. There's nothing stopping you from wrapping your API routes (only) with middleware that issues JWTs instead of a cookie. JWTs can be risky in terms of implementation however and I would often suggest just a 256 byte random token (stored in a DB or Redis against the userID) and issued via a HTTP header is a much safer way to authorize an API.